# Desktop in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, desktop

Just to clarify, this question is regarding my Desktop being in my JFrame, *not* my JFrame being on my desktop.  So...

My Desktop is showing up in my JFrame.  Why is this happening?  At no point did I ever attempt to do this.

I am switching in and out JPanels in my JFrame.  This is working just fine.  No problems there.  But the very first JPanel (my loading screen) does not draw.  Instead if just shows my Desktop.  I have:

```
public void worldMode() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Data.world = new World();
                Data.world.getSceneLibrary().addScene(new LoadingScene("Loading"));
                Data.world.setScene(Data.world.getSceneLibrary().getScene("Loading"));
                Data.world.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

where World is my JFrame, and the Scenes are my JPanels.

The JFrame shows up fine, and everything works as it should, except instead of my Loading JPanel being drawn, my Desktop is shown.  After the loading successfully finishes, the next JPanel in line loads up just fine (which is happening in World).

Seeing as there are no questions or info on putting your Desktop in a JPanel, I am rather stumped as to why this is happening.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction on where I should be looking to fix this, please?  It is very hard to resolve considering I couldn't put my desktop in there if I tried.

Also, fun fact.  When I try to take a Screen Shot, it crashes.  But it is just the full desktop in the non-maximized window.  It is definitely not just showing through.

Comment: What is your OS? If its windows, you can try if you can get a window handle of your JFrame or parent element and compare it to the getDesktopWindow() Windows API call. That should clarify if it REALLY is the desktop...

Comment: It may be a painting artifact. It can happen if you block *Event Dispatch Thread* or violate Swing's concurrency rules.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details.